# .NET Core in Linux not reading environment variable

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, environment-variables

I am trying to get the connectionString from environment variables in Linux, but the problem is that it returns null.

When i type `printenv connectionString`in termial it returns the variable, but inside application where i wrote `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connectionString")` it returns null.

Does anyone has any idea why is this happening?

p.s. I am running application in Docker.

Comment: Do you execute the 'printenv connectionString' inside the container?

Comment: @mjcs no, how can I execute that inside container, because i'm just executing it in terminal

Comment: docker exec -it “container-id” /bin/bash

Comment: @mjcs yep it returned null, so I added it using `export connectionString=...` but still when i run the image it takes as null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that environment variables from the host are not available inside the docker container. To pass the environment variable to the container you need to use the following parameter to your run command.

```
docker run -e NAME=VALUE ...
```

You can also use a file to set multiple environment variables inside the container (Also useful when you don't want sensitive data in your bash history).

```
docker run --env-file=env_file_name ...
```

Take a look at [Environment variables in docker](https://vsupalov.com/docker-environment-variables-from-host/)

Comment: I am trying to run `docker run -e connectionString connectionStringValue containerName` its tells me that `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`. While when I run `docker run containerName -e connectionString connectionStringValue` its throwing `Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: The short switch '-e' is not defined in the switch mappings.`

Comment: Yep now its working, but is there any other way to get it from environment variables so i dont need to write a lot of `-e NAME=VALUE` since in my application there are like 10 or more, and I just need to get those from environment

Comment: In my answer i described the option to use a file, this file can contain multiple envorinment variables.